# Method to take a specific class object from a generic atomic reference-- gives type error. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: java, generics, types, concurrency, descriptor

I am getting the following error:

```
    The method Complete(RDCSSDescriptor) in the type RDCSS<T> is not applicable for the arguments 
     (AtomicReference<T>)

The method Complete(RDCSSDescriptor) from the type RDCSS<T> refers to the missing type RDCSSDescriptor
```

I have a class called RDCSSDescriptor I am using to describe several different fields as atomic references of type T that contains an address. My goal is to send to complete the descriptor if the type T turns out to be the class type. I have been playing around with this for ~10 hours and I can't seem to make this type error go away. I'm not too sure why it is occurring in the first place. Could someone explain this error to me so that I can continue debugging my code? I outlined below where the type error occurs, which is in the read method.

I was considering just making the descriptor a parameter, however, the class is able to obtain different types such as Integer or String that can't be completed.

I have tried changing paramters around, I tried doing a ? type instead of T. I also tried objects and have had no luck so far.

My idea is that T can be any type, however, if T happens to be of type RDCSSDescriptor, then it will complete the read. Otherwise, it will not.

I do not have the strongest Java background so would appreciate any explanation as to why this is occurring.

I am using atomic references as I am trying to define these methods to be lock-free and thread-safe using atomics.

```
    public class RDCSS <T extends RDCSSDescriptor>
    {
       private AtomicReference<T> address;
       private AtomicReference<T> oldval_temp;
       private AtomicReference<T> result;
       private AtomicReference<T> value;
         void Complete(RDCSSDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            value = descriptor.a1;
        }
        AtomicReference<T> RDCSSRead(AtomicReference<T> address)
        {
                result = address;
                if(IsDescriptor(result))
                {
                    Complete(result); // THIS FLAGS THE TYPE ERROR
                }
                return result
       }
    }
```

The following is my RDCSSDescriptor class:

```
 class RDCSSDescriptor <T>
 {
     AtomicReference<T> address1;
     AtomicReference<T> address2;
 }
```

Comment: 1. Don't use raw types. Don't use a bounded type if you don't want to bound your type. 3. Don't expect us to guess what error you're facing.

Comment: Why do you even expect the code to work? Your parameter type and the argument try to pass in simply dont match at all.

Comment: @luk2302 I expect that by verifying that result is the same type as the descriptor class, that it will then have no issues completing.  Wouldn't the type and argument then be the same if the T was of the descriptor class? I know there is still a lot of debugging to do, but i'm confused by what exactly the error means and how to fix the error. I wanted to first understand the problem before I went in and tried to figure out what all is wrong with the code through testing.